# Nuxt JS how to update props inside the async fetch() with the new data?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

hello is possible to update props inside the async fetch after page loaded example

```js
props: {
  products: {
   type: Array,
   required:true
 }
}
async fetch() {
let data = this.products
 // data processing for display....
}

methods: {
  updateProducts() {
    return this.products.push(newdata);
  }
}
```

How to to update this.products in async fetch with the new data ? please

Comment: You can't change props directly as vue will give you warning too! but I have done it many times in my project with 2 way binding (Actually it sometimes get on nerve when you don't want your props be changed!! XD )

Comment: Hi, is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `this.$fetch()` to re-trigger a `fetch()` hook. Meanwhile, this will probably not be useful in your case. A `watch()` or just emitting a value to the parent is enough.

You can see a snippet of code here: [How to make an infinite loader in Nuxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68945621/how-to-make-an-infinite-loader-in-nuxt/68981901#68981901)

But mainly, moving the logic to a regular `method` is the way to go here (`callApi` in the example).