# How to use "Vue-infinite-loading" in nuxt without loading data by axios?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-infinite-loading

I am working on a Nuxt app. For one of my dynamic pages I want to show data with **infinite scrolling**. For that purpose I decided to use [Vue-infinite-loading](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/). I read [this article](https://sab-exp.medium.com/infinite-scroll-in-nuxt-js-f34ee86906cb) and also skimmed the documentation of **Vue-infinite-loading**. In both of them they were using **axios** module to load data step by step to show in the page when the scroll reaches to specific point in that page. But in my page the data is already present in the page according to page-id with the help of [**$strapi** module](https://strapi.nuxtjs.org/) and Nuxt **fetch** hook. The whole code of my page is like below:

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="10" class="mx-auto">
                <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">
                    در حال بارگذاری اطلاعات
                </p>
                <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
                    مشکلی در نمایش اطلاعات به وجود آمده است.
                </p>
                <div v-else>
                    <h1 v-html="this.fourType[this.nameRoute]['title']">
                    </h1>
                    <section>
                        <BaseCard 
                        v-for="item in listShow"
                        :key="item.id"
                        :imgId = "item.id" 
                        :sizeCard = "270"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:tozih>
                                {{ item.tozih }}
                            </template> 

                            <template v-slot:aout>
                                {{ item.author }}
                            </template>  
                        </BaseCard>
                    </section>
                    
                    <infinite-loading 
                    spinner="spiral"
                    @infinite="infiniteScroll"
                    >
                    </infinite-loading>
                    
                </div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            listBooks: [],
            fourType:{
                short: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتابها را به ترتیب از کوچک (کمترین تعداد صفحه) به بزرگ (بیشترین تعداد صفحه) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 1
                },
                programming: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتب مرتبط با برنامه&zwnj;نویسی (دارای برچسب برنامه&zwnj;نویسی) را به ترتیب به روزرسانی (از جدیدترین به قدیمی&zwnj;ترین) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 2
                },
                new: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتب موجود در سایت را به ترتیب به روز رسانی (از جدید به قدیم) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 3
                },
                random: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید به صورت تصادفی به مشاهده تمامی کتب موجود در سایت بپردازید:",
                    request: 4
                }
            },
            nameRoute: this.$route.params.type
        }
    }, // end of data

    computed: {
        listShow: function() {
            return [ this.listBooks[0], this.listBooks[1] ]
        }
    }, // end of computed

    methods: {
        infiniteScroll($state) {
             
                    if (this.listBooks.length > 1) {
                        this.listBooks.forEach((item) => this.listShow.push(item))
                        $state.loaded()  
                    } 
                    else {   
                        $state.complete()  
                    } 
                    
        }
    }, // end of methods

    async fetch() {
        switch (this.nameRoute) {
            case "short":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find("_sort=pageQuantity:ASC");
                break;
            case "programming":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find({ 'tags.name': ['برنامه نویسی'], _sort: 'updated_at:DESC' });
                break;
            case "new":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find("_sort=updated_at:DESC");
                break;
            default:
                this.listBooks = this.$store.getters["books/randomBook"](this.$store.state.books.list2.length);
                break;
        }
        
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

In the code I get the data in fetch hook (that is different according to page id) and then put it in **listBooks** Vue data. What I want to do is that show for example **2** data in **listBooks** first and when the scroll reached to the end of the second data (second card here), I show the rest of data step by step with infinite scrolling method. So I used a **Computed data** called **listShow** and used it in v-for. Then I put the code I thought that maybe it might work inside **infiniteScroll** method. But obviously that does not work, because I just guess that. If anyone know that how change that code to work and show data in infinite scrolling please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: No need for `[ this.listBooks[0], this.listBooks[1] ]`, keep a single array and add new values inside of it based on your scrolling. Like `10 items + (10 items * amount of times you reached the infinite loader bottom border)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally with the help of **kissu** answer and with the inspiration of the code of [the article mentioned in my question](https://sab-exp.medium.com/infinite-scroll-in-nuxt-js-f34ee86906cb) found the solution. Here I will post the code of my whole Nuxt page to show the answer for using other developers:

```html
<template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="10" class="mx-auto">
                <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">
                    در حال بارگذاری اطلاعات
                </p>
                <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">
                    مشکلی در نمایش اطلاعات به وجود آمده است.
                </p>
                <div v-else>
                    <h1 v-html="this.fourType[this.nameRoute]['title']">
                    </h1>
                    <section>
                        <BaseCard 
                        v-for="item in list2"
                        :key="item.id"
                        :imgId = "item.id" 
                        :sizeCard = "270"
                        >
                            <template v-slot:tozih>
                                {{ item.tozih }}
                            </template> 

                            <template v-slot:aout>
                                {{ item.author }}
                            </template>  
                        </BaseCard>
                    </section>
                    
                    <infinite-loading 
                    spinner="spiral"
                    @infinite="infiniteScroll"
                    >
                    </infinite-loading>
                    
                </div>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            listBooks: [],
            page: 0,
            list2: [],
            fourType:{
                short: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتابها را به ترتیب از کوچک (کمترین تعداد صفحه) به بزرگ (بیشترین تعداد صفحه) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 1
                },
                programming: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتب مرتبط با برنامه&zwnj;نویسی (دارای برچسب برنامه&zwnj;نویسی) را به ترتیب به روزرسانی (از جدیدترین به قدیمی&zwnj;ترین) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 2
                },
                new: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید کتب موجود در سایت را به ترتیب به روز رسانی (از جدید به قدیم) مشاهده نمایید:",
                    request: 3
                },
                random: {
                    title: "در این قسمت می&zwnj;توانید به صورت تصادفی به مشاهده تمامی کتب موجود در سایت بپردازید:",
                    request: 4
                }
            },
            nameRoute: this.$route.params.type
        }
    }, // end of data

    methods: {
        infiniteScroll($state) {
        setTimeout(() => {    
            let emptyArr = [];
            for (let index = this.page*10; index < this.page*10+10; index++) {
                if (this.listBooks[index]) {
                    emptyArr.push(this.listBooks[index])
                }
            }
            
            if (emptyArr.length > 0) {
            emptyArr.forEach(
                (item) => this.list2.push(item)
            )
            $state.loaded();
            } else {
            $state.complete()
            }
            this.page++
        }, 500)            
                    
        }
    }, // end of methods

    async fetch() {
        switch (this.nameRoute) {
            case "short":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find("_sort=pageQuantity:ASC");
                break;
            case "programming":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find({ 'tags.name': ['برنامه نویسی'], _sort: 'updated_at:DESC' });
                break;
            case "new":
                this.listBooks = await this.$strapi.$books.find("_sort=updated_at:DESC");
                break;
            default:
                this.listBooks = this.$store.getters["books/randomBook"](this.$store.state.books.list2.length);
                break;
        }
        
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

> the **two** important changes were:

1- Using an empty array called **list2** in my Vue data instead of Vue **computed data**.

2- Using a variable called **emptyArr** in my **infiniteScroll** method that holds only for example **10** items of the original data (Vue listBooks data) and is showing them with scrolling the page each time that 10 data passed from the user view.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, an infinite loader is used to have a small subset of data that you then expand for performance reasons: not having to load 100 elements at once but 10, then 10 more etc...

If you already have the data locally at once and like the behavior of it, without any "pagination" needed from your Strapi backend, you can always watch for the [`@infinite` event](https://peachscript.github.io/vue-infinite-loading/api/#infinite) and increase the size of your initial array of elements with the next one.

Saying that if you display 10 of them, want to scroll down and show 10 more: display the first 10, then when the `infinite` event is triggered, append 10 more items to your initial array and so on.

My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981901/8816585) may help understand it a bit more.

PS: beware of some [reactivity issues](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays) that you may face one day when dealing with arrays.

Comment: I did not understand the meaning of "@infinite event" that you mentioned. do you mean that I must replace ```@infinite="infiniteScroll"``` in the **infinite-loading** component in template part with something else? Also I want to know that my code must be **asynchronous** to work perfectly or not?

Comment: @hamid-davodi no, `@infinite="infiniteScroll"` is totally fine. I was just emphasizing what you should focus regarding the listener but here it's all good yeah. Your code **may** be async if you need it. If you want to use `axios` for example, yeah it needs to be async. If you don't want/need to, and just have your data already fetched from Strapi with the whole data, you don't need to go async on top of it. Usually, frontend is a lot of async tho!